# Компиляции GTK+ кода

Tags: c++, gtk

Как скомпилировать GTK+ ?! Почитал мануалы и там подключается "опции" но  чего то не хватает.

`pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`

**Error**

```
/home/hays/program/test/GTK+/main.c:3:43: error: unknown type name ‘GtkEventAny’
 static gint delete_event_cb(GtkWidget *w, GtkEventAny *e,
                                           ^
/home/hays/program/test/GTK+/main.c: In function ‘main’:
/home/hays/program/test/GTK+/main.c:21:24: error: ‘GTK_WINDOW’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW), "Hello");
                        ^
/home/hays/program/test/GTK+/main.c:21:24: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/home/hays/program/test/GTK+/main.c:21:3: error: too few arguments to function ‘gtk_window_set_title’
   gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW), "Hello");
   ^
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkdialog.h:33:0,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkaboutdialog.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:31,
                 from /home/hays/program/test/GTK+/main.c:1:
/usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkwindow.h:147:12: note: declared here
 void       gtk_window_set_title                (GtkWindow           *window,
            ^
/home/hays/program/test/GTK+/main.c:21:35: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
   gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW), "Hello");
                                   ^
/home/hays/program/test/GTK+/main.c:21:3: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
   gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW), "Hello");
   ^
/home/hays/program/test/GTK+/main.c:21:44: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
   gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW), "Hello");
                                            ^
/home/hays/program/test/GTK+/main.c:21:44: error: expected statement before ‘)’ token
/home/hays/program/test/GTK+/main.c:24:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gtk_signal_connect’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   gtk_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT(window), "delete_event",
   ^
/home/hays/program/test/GTK+/main.c:24:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘GTK_OBJECT’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
/home/hays/program/test/GTK+/main.c:25:22: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                      GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(delete_event_cb), NULL);
                      ^
/home/hays/program/test/GTK+/main.c:25:38: error: ‘delete_event_cb’ undeclared (first use in this function)
                      GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(delete_event_cb), NULL);
                                      ^
/home/hays/program/test/GTK+/main.c: In function ‘button_click_cb’:
/home/hays/program/test/GTK+/main.c:49:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gtk_label_get’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   gtk_label_get(GTK_LABEL(label), &text);
   ^
/home/hays/program/test/GTK+/main.c:51:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘g_str_reverse’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   g_str_reverse(tmp);
   ^
/home/hays/program/test/GTK+/main.c:52:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gtl_label_set_text’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   gtl_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(label), tmp);
   ^
/home/hays/program/test/GTK+/main.c: At top level:
/home/hays/program/test/GTK+/main.c:35:13: warning: ‘delete_event_cb’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static gint delete_event_cb(GtkWidget *window, GdkEventAny *e,
```

**Code**

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static gint delete_event_cb(GtkWidget *w, GtkEventAny *e,
                            gpointer data);
static void button_click_cb(GtkWidget *w, gpointer data);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *button;
  GtkWidget *label;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  button = gtk_button_new();
  label = gtk_label_new("Hello, World!");

  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(button), label);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), button);

  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW, "Hello");
  gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(button), 10);

  gtk_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT(window), "delete_event",
                     GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(delete_event_cb), NULL);
  gtk_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT(button), "clicked",
                     GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(button_click_cb), label);

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  gtk_main();
  return 0;
}

static gint delete_event_cb(GtkWidget *window, GdkEventAny *e,
                            gpointer data)
{
  gtk_main_quit();
  return FALSE;
}

static void button_click_cb(GtkWidget *w, gpointer data)
{
  GtkWidget *label;
  gchar *text;
  gchar *tmp;

  label = GTK_WIDGET(data);
  gtk_label_get(GTK_LABEL(label), &text);
  tmp = g_strdup(text);
  g_str_reverse(tmp);
  gtl_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(label), tmp);
  g_free(tmp);
}
```

Comment: Вообще-то надо в первую очередь читать ошибки, выдаваемые компилятором. Иначе зачем их компилятор выдает? И хотя бы для начала исправить синтаксические ошибки типа этой  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW), "Hello");

Comment: http://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/gtk/node39.html соурс брал от сюда без  изменение

Comment: Но вы видите, что здесь gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW), "Hello"); лишняя закрывающаяся скобка после GTK_WINDOW? И что такое GTK_WINDOW? Как я понимаю, вы должны установить заголовок для объекта window. ,

Comment: Это совершенно безграмотный источник информации по GTK. Например, один из заголовков выглядит так:" Осознание, отображение и показывание". Что это еще за "Осознание"? Может быть имеется в виду "Создание"? Надо читать первоисточники, а не безграмотные переводы со множеством опечаток.

Comment: Послушав вашего совета решил скомпилировать из первоисточника 
https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html#id-1.2.3.5
Получил ряд ошибок http://pastebin.com/xvUewdcP
собирал с теме же флагами `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`

Comment: Код из первоисточника отличается от того, что вы здесь привели? Те ошибки, которые присутствует по ссылке, говорят о том, что соответствующая библиотека не подключена к проекту.

Comment: А разве эта директива не подключает библиотеку `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` ?! 
Если нет то какую нужно подключить?!
Делал выводы из ходя из этого  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546877/compiling-and-linking-gtk-3-with-c-project-on-ubuntu

Comment: Ну, так там же дан ответ, как надо написать командную строку.

Comment: Всё скомпилировал пример оказывается в IDE нужно было указывать в 2 местах точки подключение директивы.
 Спасибо за помощь !

Answer (score 1):

http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/x/gtk3.html
проверь зависимости и  версию компилятора.

Comment: Какое отношение к синтаксическим ошибкам компиляции имеет версия компилятора?

Comment: поесните как это сделать 
P.s пакеты ставил через synaptic -> "libgtk-3-dev"

Comment: Ну я думаю так "если компилятор выдает ошибки значит что то не доустановлено но если ошибки продолжают идти то лучше обновить компилятор то рекомендованной версии а не лезть в код и править кучу строк".

Comment: Посмотри на предмет:  at-spi2-atk-2.16.0, gdk-pixbuf-2.31.6, and Pango-1.36.8. dpkg --list|grep <pkg>

Comment: @Eugene P. Вы сначала внимательно посмотрите приведенной код в вопросе, прежде чем советовать всякую ерунду.

Comment: Ну если указание на то чего возможно не хватает это ерунда тогда ладно. Не буду указывать на код который уже был тысячу и один раз собран без видимых проблем.

Comment: @Eugene P. Как может быть "собрано" данное предложение gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW), "Hello"); тысячу и один раз Объясните пожалуйста?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow а что не так? ааа хэндлер то не указан...

Comment: gtk_window_set_title((GTK_WINDOW(window), "Hello"); так правильнее. ок - съел :)

Comment: @Eugene P.  Убрал я свой голос против вашего сообщения, так как это ваше первое сообщение на этом форуме. На stackoverflow.com вас бы заклевали.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow спс. Первый раз как в первый класс :) Решил поотвечать пока жду ответ на свой вопрос.